# How to make actions after my alert dismissed in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, alert

I want to make some actions after my alert dismissed.

I know u may tell me its easy by using buttons handler but my question not for this case. I need help in case I didn't click on alert buttons such as when I click on back button of my phone then nothing happen.

So is there any way to check if my alert dismissed then run another action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `onDidDismiss` function:

```
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      ...
    });
    alert.present();
    alert.onDidDismiss(() => {
      //Your code here
    })
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks

Comment: In Ionic 4, it should be `alert.onDidDismiss().then((data) => {});`